# :user-valid not working for input type date, and neither does :user-invalid

Tags: html, css, validation, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm encountering an issue with the CSS pseudo-class **`:user-valid`** not behaving as expected for an input of type date. Similarly, **`:user-invalid`** doesn't seem to produce the desired results. However, **`:valid`** is working correctly.

Here's a snippet:

```css
input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input:user-valid {
  border: 1px solid green; /* Not working as intended for date input */
}

input:user-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red; /* Also not working for date input */
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="trip-start" value="2024-02-15" min="2024-02-10" max="2024-02-20" />
```

The styling for :valid is applied, but neither :user-valid nor :user-invalid seems to have any effect for a date input. I have found no information indicating that date inputs don't work with these rules. I also tested these rules with an email input, and everything works correctly in that case. Any suggestions or insights on how to make :user-valid and :user-invalid work with a date input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Working on Chrome and Firefox but not on Edge (121) to me.

Comment: @SyndRain Yes, I use Edge, and I hadn't considered testing on other browsers. I can confirm that it works for Firefox but not for Chrome (121) in my case.

Comment: For me on WIndows10: Edge not working; Chrome works for OK input, not for invalid input; Firefox works.